# speed test Objects and Maps

Tags: javascript, object, maps

Is this a good way to test speed for Objects and Maps? Because I read that Maps ought to be faster, which is not the result of my test, where results are like this: 'Map takes: 87ms, Object takes: 79ms'

```
const testObject = {
     name: "John",
     age: "27"
   }

   const testMap = new Map();

   testMap.set("name", "John");
   testMap.set("age", 27);

   // test for Object

   const startObj = new Date();

   for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
     console.log(testObject);
   }

   const endObj = new Date();
   const elapsedTimeObj = endObj - startObj;
   console.log(elapsedTimeObj);

   // test for Map

   const startMap = new Date();

   for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
     console.log(testMap);
   }

   const endMap = new Date();
   const elapsedTimeMap = endMap - startMap;
   console.log(elapsedTimeMap);

   console.log("Map takes: " + elapsedTimeMap + "ms" + ", " + "Object takes: " + elapsedTimeObj + "ms" ); 
   // results in: 'Map takes: 87ms, Object takes: 79ms'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run your example in my browser, it gives me:

```
Map takes: 3ms, Object takes: 10ms
```

Maybe you have a slow and old browser, but Map is actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the answer: I should not have logged the entire object, but only the items, testObject.name and testMap.name, so the output is exactly the same: "John". It gives 'Map takes: 223ms, Object takes: 262ms' as a result.